# Rotated Curly Brackets Along Arrow (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, brackets

I am trying to do a diagram to show the nature of Principal Component Analysis. I have the following code, wherein I would like to have rotated curly brackets under the Principal Component Vectors to specify their length.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$z(x_{0})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$z(x_{1})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8) node[above right]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{1}$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{0}$};

\clip[rotate=45] (4, 0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.0);
 \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black, rotate = 45]  (4 + 2.5*rand,1*rand) circle (0.05);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Result of Code]

What I would like is the following:

[image: Wanted Result]

Is there a way of doing this? I am very new to Tikz, so any pointers would be fantastic!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! This can be done with the `brace` decoration.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$z(x_{0})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$z(x_{1})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8) node[above right]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{1}$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{0}$};
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8)
node[midway,below left=2pt]{$\lambda$};
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt,mirror}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5)
node[midway,below right=2pt]{$\lambda$};
\clip[rotate=45] (4, 0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.0);
 \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black, rotate = 45]  (4 + 2.5*rand,1*rand) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to shorten the brace as in your screen shot, use e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$z(x_{0})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$z(x_{1})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8) node[above right]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{1}$}
coordinate[pos=0.9] (aux1);
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{0}$}
coordinate[pos=0.95] (aux2);
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (aux1)
node[midway,below left=2pt]{$\lambda$};
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt,mirror}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (aux2)
node[midway,below right=2pt]{$\lambda$};
\clip[rotate=45] (4, 0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.0);
 \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black, rotate = 45]  (4 + 2.5*rand,1*rand) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would perhaps add a tiny halo around `\lambda` and the brace to prevent the plot from cluttering.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
 \draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$z(x_{0})$};
 \draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$z(x_{1})$};
 \draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8) node[above right]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{1}$}
 coordinate[pos=0.9] (aux1);
 \draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{0}$}
 coordinate[pos=0.95] (aux2);
\begin{scope}
\pgfmathsetseed{23}
\clip[rotate=45] (4, 0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.0);
 \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black, rotate = 45]  (4 + 2.5*rand,1*rand) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{scope} 
 \draw[thick,white,double=black,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (aux1)
 node[midway,below left=2pt,black]{\contour{white}{$\lambda$}};
 \draw[thick,white,double=black,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt,mirror}] (2.75, 2.75) -- (aux2)
 node[midway,below right=2pt,black]{\contour{white}{$\lambda$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is of course just an option.

Answer (score 0):

Standard math `{` can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right]{$z(x_{0})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above]{$z(x_{1})$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (1.6, 3.8) node[above right]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{1}$};
\draw[line width = 0.5mm, ->] (2.75, 2.75) -- (5, 5) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{\text{pc}}_{0}$};

\node[rotate=-45] at (4.1,3.5) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont$\Bigg\}$};
\node[rotate=229] at (1.8,3) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont$\big\}$};



\clip[rotate=45] (4, 0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.0);
 \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black, rotate = 45]  (4 + 2.5*rand,1*rand) circle (0.05);
    }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]